# Eigenvalues of Product of 2 hermitian operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

Let $A$ and $B$ be two Hermitian operators. Let $C$ be another operator such that $C = AB$. What can we say about Eigenvalues of $C$? Will they be real/imaginary/complex? What I did was to search for examples. The following were examples (in matrix representation) I looked for:
$ A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $ B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ to get a hermitian matrix and so real eigenvalues.
Next I tried:
$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $ B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ to get Anti-Hermitian matrix and so imaginary eigenvalues.
Is there a more concrete way of solving this? Can we have a general complex number as eigenvalues for the product of the Hermitian Matrices?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/666144/2451

Comment: I was not aware of this duplicate. I posted the general solution here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/666155/226902

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of commutator and Anticommutator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/666144/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, we can say that $C=AB$ will have real, imaginary and complex eigenvalues (complex of the form $z=a+ib$ where and $\{a,b\in \mathbb{R}\mid a,b \ne 0\}$ as shown in the comments by Mark and Qmechanic's answer). For example, if
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 1& 0
\end{bmatrix}\ \ \text{and}\ \  B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
 0& -1
\end{bmatrix}$$ where $$AB=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-1 \\ 
 1& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$ will *not* have real, but imaginary eigenvalues.

However, one thing we can say is that if $A$ and $B$ commute then $C=AB$ will always have *real* eigenvalues, since the eigenvalues of all Hermitian operators are real.

So if $$C=AB$$ then $$C^\dagger =(AB)^\dagger =B^\dagger A^\dagger =BA$$ since $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian, and clearly $$C^\dagger =C$$ if $$[A,B]=AB-BA=0\rightarrow AB=BA$$ This means that $C^\dagger =C$ only if $A$ and $B$ commute in which case $C$ will have real eigenvalues.

Comment: sir, I meant that can we have eigenvalues of the form $a + ib $ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a, b \neq 0$

Comment: I'd like to add in @josephh ' s answer that if anti-commutator of $A $ and $B$ is 0, then C will be anti-hermitian and thus will have purely imaginary eigenvalues

Comment: @josephh It's not true that the eigenvalues are either real or imaginary. The matrix $AB$ generally has both Hermitian and anti-Hermitian components, so the eigenvalues can be any complex number. Consider for example $A = \sigma_z$ and $B=\sigma_z + \sigma_x$, then $AB = \mathbb{1} + i \sigma_y$, where $\sigma_{x,y,z}$ are Pauli matrices. The eigenvalues of $AB$ are $1\pm i$.

Comment: I agree with @MarkMitchison.  It is possible to show that (in general) the eigenvalues of $AB$ are complex and come in conjugate pairs (as in the example in the comment of Mark Mitchinson), see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/666155/226902

Comment: LifelongLearner Take note that there are cases where the eigenvalues can be in the form a+ib as Mark Mitchison has shown above using the spin matrices (Thanks Mark). This means the eigenvalues, in the general case can be purely real, or purely imaginary _and_ complex.  But it does not change the fact that the product $AB$ will have pure real eigenvalues if $A$ and $B$ commute.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Assuming that $A,B$ are self-adjoint, the product $AB$ does not need to be diagonalizable. And if $AB$ is diagonalizable, the eigenvalues need not be real or imaginary.

Example 1: $AB$ is not diagonalizable:
$$A~=~\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad\wedge\quad B~=~\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\quad\Rightarrow\quad   AB~=~\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Example 2: $AB$ has complex eigenvalues:
$$A~=~\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\quad\wedge\quad B~=~\begin{pmatrix} 0 & b \cr b^{\ast} & 0 \end{pmatrix}\quad\Rightarrow\quad AB~=~\begin{pmatrix} b^{\ast} & 0 \cr 0 & b  \end{pmatrix}. $$